# How to avoid caching of calling functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I use this code for create work folder and work calendar after a user edit some cells but I have some problems: createFolder() wait for return of createCalendar() and only then it performe.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var eRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActive().getActiveRange();
  var eRow = eRange.getRow();
  var eCol = eRange.getColumn();

  if (eCol == 1) {
        creatieFolder(eRow);
        createCalendar(eRow);
  }
}

function createFolder(eRow) {
    var folderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID).createFolder("test name").getId();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActive().getRange(eRow, 2).setValue(folderID);

  return folderID;
}

function createCalendar(eRow) {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar("test name");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActive().getRange(eRow, 3).setValue(calendar.getId());
  return calendar.getId();
}
```

I suppose about caching because I see the value of folderID in 2nd column after performing createCalendar() at the same time as I see calendarID in 3rd column.
And I want to see folderID before calendarID. How to do this?

Comment: Flush the write buffer between calls if you need to disable Google's write caching optimization.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks a lot! It solves my problems.